# Redux devtools showing undefined state but rendering perfectly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-devtools

I am trying out Redux Toolkit now as I have been using the previous method of Redux in my React applications. So after setting up everything and fetching the data, the Redux DevTools in my browser shows `undefined` in the state tab. But action tab shows the type, payload and meta perfectly. The data is also being rendered perfectly without any issues.

This is how the Action tab looks like:

[image]

And here's the State tab:

[image]

Isn't it supposed to be populated with all the data? Why is it undefined?

Here's the code:

productSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import productService from './productService';

const initialState = {
    products: null,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: ''
}

// Fetch Products 
export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk('product/getAllProducts', async (thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        return await productService.getAllProducts();
    } catch (error) {
        const message = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString();
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
})

export const productSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'product',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isSuccess = false;
            state.isError = false;
            state.message = ''
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(getProducts.pending, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = true;
            })
            .addCase(getProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.isSuccess = true;
                state.products = action.payload.data;
            })
            .addCase(getProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.isError = true;
                state.message = action.payload.message;
                state.products = null;
            })
    }
});

export const { reset } = productSlice.actions;
export default productSlice.reducer;
```

productService.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = '/api/products';

const getAllProducts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
    return response.data;
}

const productService = {
    getAllProducts
}

export default productService;
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import productReducer from './product/productSlice';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        products: productReducer
    }
});

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you registered this slice incorrectly in the store. There is 'getProducts' slice name in the store instead of 'product'.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the store. I have updated it now. Please check,

Comment: getProducts is the name of the thunk function. I put products in the store. How did it get changed? Lol. And how do I fix it?

Comment: @Zak not sure if it causes the error, but try to use 'product' or 'products' in both slice and store registration

Comment: @Zak try changing products: productReducer to product: productReducer

Comment: Okay I'll get back to you within a moment.

Comment: I just changed products: productReducer to product: productReducer. It is still ```getProducts: undefined``` in devtools.

Comment: Okay so I changed it to getProducts: productReducer...and it worked.

Comment: I guess the thunk function name and store name should be the same.

Comment: @Zak yeah you could try changing thunk name to getAllProducts too, other than that code looks good to me

Comment: Thanks. put the solution as an answer.

Comment: @Zak thanks, if you find the issue please let me know I'm curious what wrong with this code

Answer (score 2):

I just remove devtool extension and reinstalled it, it works for me :)

Comment: I have been trying to find a solution for so long and tried almost everything except for this. Whoever is struggling this is worth a shot might save a lot of time doing complex integrations. I do not know why it works but it works.